# How to create Cover Pages in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

Does anyone know how to create new cover pages in *Microsoft Word 2010/2011*?  I tried my best to find some information in the web but all I found was instructions on how to insert the prebuild cover pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make the page and add it to the Cover Pages by selecting the page and opening the cover pages dropdown. At the bottom is an option to save the selection to the gallery or select the page and hit Alt-F3 and pick Cover Pages for the Gallery option.

Answer (score 0):

In the 2007 version, its ALT>N>V

For 2010,

1. On the Insert tab, in the Pages group, click Cover Page.
2. Click a cover page layout from the gallery of options.
   After you insert a cover page, you can replace the sample text with your own text by clicking to select an area of the cover page, such as the title, and typing your text.

Just by the way...

If you insert another cover page in the document, the new cover page will replace the first cover page you inserted.
To replace a cover page created in an earlier version of Word, you must delete the first cover page manually, and then add a cover page with a design from the Word gallery.
To delete a cover page inserted with Word, click the Insert tab, click Cover pages in the Pages group, and then click Remove Current Cover Page.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/add-a-cover-page-HA010368884.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Others have pointed out there is an option to save the cover page at the bottom of the cover pages dropdown menu. However this may be greyed out. In which case, select all the content (e.g. with Ctrl-A) and the button should become available.
(This applies in Office 2013.)

Comment: Question was about Office 2010 or Office 2011 not Office 2013.